# Apply IMPORTRANGE to filtered array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, googlesheets4

I have a series of Sheet IDs that I want to import data from. The list is dynamic.
I want to pull columns A:C from each sheet in that array.

I have tried using arrayformula and a map-lambda formula.
Arrayformula pulls data from the first sheet, and map-lambda returns "Result should be a single row." error.

I have sheet1 with column A:A that holds the sheet IDs.
On a different tab, I want to pull data from each sheet ID, tab sheet1, columns A:C.

Each array is variable - the number of entries in the sheet IDs can increase/decrease and the number of rows in A:C can vary (the number of columns is always the same).

I would love any input on this.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming:*

*`Sheet 1`→`Column_A` has the **Sheet_IDs***

*you wish to import from tab `Sheet 1`→`A:C columns` from all target Sheet_IDs*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(Sheet1!A:A,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,importrange(c,"Sheet1!A:C"),filter(Σ,byrow(Σ,lambda(Λ,counta(Λ)>0)))))))
```

***logic***:

`tocol(Sheet1!A:A,1)` →. *picking sheet IDs from here*

`vstack(a,let(Σ,importrange(c,"Sheet1!A:C"` →. *stacks vertically one sheet data (3 columns) at a time*

`filter(Σ,byrow(Σ,lambda(Λ,counta(Λ)>0))))` →. *eliminating lines where all the cells(in a row) are blank*

Comment: It works, but by god, I have no idea what's happening here. 
Care to explain a little ? 
Thanks !

Comment: added some basic explanation to the answer, I'd suggest you to look into *lambda/map/reduce* functions & the formula would be more clear/easier once you get to know them...